# Google API Oauth consent screen stuck in verification for almost a year

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I built a Chrome Extension using the Google Slides API ~8 months ago, with users having to sign in with the OAuth consent screen as to be able to use the extension. The extension has over a thousand users, and for the past weeks I've had reports of people seeing an error that says "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app".

I checked and indeed the OAuth page was still "being verified", although it still said it would only take a few days / several weeks. I'm not using any sensitive scopes either, so it all seems very odd. If the app didn't meet the criteria I would have been rejected, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So my question is, how can I get it verified, or if anything rejected so that I can make a new submission? I looked all over the place and I haven't found a way to get it unstuck. I'm pretty sure 8 months for verification isn't normal whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google seems to manually validate each OAuth screen. That's a long (and costly process), but to my experience, it generally takes 24 hours if you don't use any sensitive/restrictive scopes. As it's your case apparently, I presume your submission has probably being lost somewhere.

My recommendations:

1. Check in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) the status of your OAuth Screen. After logged in Google Cloud console, click on the hamburger icon and select "APIs & Services" > "OAuth consent screen". At the top of the page you will see the status. If it's something like "pending verification", go to step 2. Otherwise, make sure the form is completed and submit it to verification again.
2. Search in your emails if you have been contacted by "**api-oauth-dev-verification-reply [at] google [dot] com**" (the address might slightly change as they use a ticketing solution). Maybe they tried to contact you but the email went to spam?
3. Get in touch with the OAuth team by emailing "**api-oauth-dev-verification-reply [at] google [dot] com**". Make sure to add your
   Google Project number in your email, so they will be able to check
   what's wrong.

Disclaimer: I don't work at Google. But I'm bit familiar with that process now :)

Comment: I've looked through my emails but I only have a "Verification request received" email. I may have to get in touch then, thanks!

Comment: The email address now automatically replies with this: `Please note that your email was not received because api-dev-oauth-verification@google.com is not a monitored alias.`

Comment: The email address has slightly changed to `api-oauth-dev-verification-reply`. Editing the post;